Put an overlaying box above header
I have created a code for the heading but I can't figure out how top put the box overlay it and it should be like this
sample of overlayed box
I've tried to do with rows and column with bootstrap but it can't be overlayed
Here is the html code
<html data-bs-theme="light" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>Coba KP</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <section class="py-4s" style="background-image: url('background.jpeg');background-size: contain;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 200">
                <path fill="#ffffff" d="M0,192L1440,128L1440,320L0,320Z"></path>
            </svg></section>
    </header>
</body>

</html>

Anyone can give me an idea about how to do it especially in the code? Thanks in advance

The most straightforward way to achieve a partial overlay is to use a negative margin.


.d1, .d2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.d1 {
  background: red;
}

.d2 {
  background: blue;
  margin: -50px 20% 0 20%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>




Does the same rule apply if the overlay are completely above the background?

No, in that case I would tend to use position: relative on the container and position: absolute on the overlay.
